# How to install the latest SaltStack packages for CentOS 7

Tags: linux, yum, upgrade

I am trying to install the latest version of the salt-minion package (2018.3.1). But in my yum repository, the latest available version is 2015.5.10-2.el7.

```
yum --showduplicates list salt-minion
Available Packages salt-minion.noarch  2015.5.10-2.el7
```

I have tried the following commands to no effect.

```
yum clean all
yum makecache fast
yum update
```

Comment: Instead of EPEL, use the official SaltStack repo for RHEL: https://repo.saltstack.com/#rhel

Comment: Now you're making assumptions. I did not downvote your question. But I do think it could have been resolved with a brief Google search, which is what led me to the SaltStack documentation and therefore the official repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment to a complete answer.

The `salt-minion` package is part of the Salt configuration management software. The [Installation Documentation for Salt](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/rhel.html) lists two ways of obtaining the packages required by Salt.

1. Use the official SaltStack repository.
2. Use the community-maintained EPEL repository.

The official repository contains the most up-to-date packages including the current version of Salt, 2018.3. The EPEL repository contains a much older version of the package, which is 2015.5.

As of version 2015.8, the EPEL repository is no longer required for installing Salt on RHEL systems.Therefore, the new packages may be installed purely from the offical repository. The official SaltStack repository for RHEL is located [here](https://repo.saltstack.com/#rhel).

The EPEL repository appears to have been abandoned sometime back due to a dependency problem - the installation document mentions that the packages `python-crypto-2.6.1` and `python-tornado-4.21` were not available in EPEL. These packages are now available as part of CentOS since 7.4.1708. `python-crypto-2.6.1` is available as part of the Extras repository, and `python-tornado-4.21` is available as part of the base repository.